# Checkbox with value from user input

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have some checkboxes people need to fill in, but I want 1 checkbox to be so users can make their own input.

My question is: How can I get the user to fill in their own input so I can store it in my database?

Comment: `<input type="text">` …?

Comment: It has to be a checkbox. So is that possible that way?

Comment: A checkbox can be checked, or not checked. It doesn’t allow for any other sort of user input.

Comment: so there is no way that I can change the value from user input?

Comment: You need to _get_ that “user input” first of all. How you expect that to happen, if not via a text input field or something similar?

Comment: I get that, but they first need to check the checkbox and then fill in the user input

Comment: So your _actual_ question is/becomes, “how can I show a text field when a specific checkbox is checked?” - start doing some research on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this..

```js
$(".addNew").click(function(){
  $(".newInput").show();
});
```

```css
.newInput{
  display:none;
 }
.addNew{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox"> red
<input type="checkbox"> green
<input type="text" class="newInput">
<br>
<span class="addNew">Add own</span>
```

Comment: Thanks! this was the solution I was looking for